# How do I use a Saved Search as a Desktop Background Folder?

Tags: macos, finder, search, smart-folders

I want to use my movie library's Posters and Artwork as a cycling background. The problem is movie managers place each movie in a folder, and then a subfolder for artwork (jpgs). And choosing a Folder for Backgrounds is not recursive.

In Finder I ran a search for ‘type:image’ then saved that as "Movies.savedSearch".

Then in the Desktop & Screen Saver preference pane, I tried to add that folder, but it won't drag-n-drop, and if I hit the + to select the folder, it is greyed out / not accessible.

Any idea how to get this to work?

Comment: If I had more rep I would have created a "savedSearch" tag.

Comment: You're looking for the [smart-folders] tag.

Answer (score 2):

This isn't possible. Smart folders are saved as .savedSearch and aren't real folders, so you can't add them to lists requiring folders.

Comment: Hm. Folder aliases work. I figured a Smart Folder would, too. Any workaround for this... short of making an alias of every jpg into a real folder?

Comment: @Jules Making an alias of each jpg might not be too bad with a script which you could run in the background or run on demand.